# I created a stored procedure getting begin syntax error

Tags: sql-server, database

I created a stored procedure, but I am getting a begin syntax error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Upload_Address
      @COM_Addresstbl 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO COM_Address(Email, CompanyName)
        SELECT Email, CompanyName 
        FROM COM_Address
END
```

Comment: you need to define the data type for `@COM_Addresstbl` of the input parameter

Comment: Why do you even have the parameter `@COM_Addresstbl`, when it's never used in your SP? Your SP is just duplicating the data for the columns `Email` and `CompanyName` in the table `COM_Address`. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here, as I doubt it's to duplicate the data.

Comment: What exactly are you asking ? Can you explain what this procedure should do, because even if we correct the syntax so the error goes away, this procedure does nothing else but duplicate all data from one table. The parameter is not even used at all

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the type of input, for example, type **nvarchar(50)** for 
**COM_Addresstbl**

You can use the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Upload_Address
  @COM_Addresstbl  nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO COM_Address(Email, CompanyName)
    SELECT Email, CompanyName 
    FROM COM_Address
END
```

Comment: The parameter is not used at all. I dont see how this helps. The OP has to explain better what his problem is and what he is trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1):

You need to define table type like given below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Upload_Address
      @COM_Addresstbl tabletypename readonly 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO COM_Address(Email, CompanyName)
        SELECT Email, CompanyName 
        FROM @COM_Addresstbl
END
```

**how to create table type **

```
CREATE Type tabletypename As table ( Email varchar(max), CompanyName
 varchar(max) )
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE Upload_Address
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
INSERT INTO COM_Address(Email, CompanyName)
    SELECT Email, CompanyName 
    FROM COM_Address
```

END